# Using std::ios_base::Init to properly initialize globals

Tags: c++

I have a `My_Singleton` global object `singleton_obj` that **I want to ensure that it is properly initialized before it is used and there is only a single instance of it**. I have learned about [Nifty counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) here, and I found some other answers about including `std::ios_base::Init` object in the class can achieve the same effect.

```cpp
/*My_Singleton.h */
#include <iostream>
class My_Singleton
{
    My_Singleton(My_Singleton&&) =delete;
    My_Singleton& operator=(My_Singleton&&) =delete;
    My_Singleton(My_Singleton const&) =delete;
    My_Singleton& operator=(My_Singleton const&) =delete;
    std::ios_base::Init initalizer;
public: 
    My_Singleton() =default;
    ~My_Singleton() =default;
};

extern My_Singleton singleton_obj;

/*My_Singleton.cpp*/
#include "My_Singleton.h"
My_Singleton singleton_obj;
```

My question are:
1. Is this the correct way of doing it? If not, please provide a fix
2. How does `std::ios_base::Init` implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ensure that it is properly initialized before it is used and there is only a single instance of it
>
> Is this the correct way of doing it?

No. `std::ios_base::Init` is used to order initialization of standard streams `cout` `cin` etc. The way you used it would make sure that standard streams are initialized before your object is initialized and destroyed after your object is destroyed.

> If not, please provide a fix

The usual way to protect against static initialization fiasco is to provide a function that returns a reference to an object with static storage duration. Because the object with static storage duration will be initialized when entering the function, such function protects against the fiasco.

```
    My_Singleton& singleton_obj() {
       static My_Singleton obj;
       return obj;
    }
```

Placing such function inside your class and making constructor private will effectively disallow constructing other instances of this object.

How to implement a singleton with only one instance can be found in numerous places on the web, ex. [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/9072753) has ready-to-use pattern.

> How does std::ios_base::Init implemented?

The constructor of `std::ios_base::Init` calls placement new on standard streams. That way, calling `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` will make sure, that standard streams are initialized. It has a counter, so it calls the placement new only once and destroys standard streams only when the counter reaches 0.

The implementation in libstdc++ can be found [ios_init.cc](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/ios_init.cc.html#80),  variables are defined in [ios.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/ios.cc#L72) and class definition is in [bits/ios_base.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h#L603). Each transaction unit that uses streams has it's own [static ios_base::Init __ioinit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/iostream#L74) object.

The implementation in libc++ can be found in [iostream.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/iostream.cpp#L148), global object is declared [in the same file](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/iostream.cpp#L80) and class definition is in [include/ios](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ios#L447).